# Scene transition image drawn in tiles during transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm facing weird drawing issue with scene transitions (**running with Nexus 5x 6.0.1 platform**)

I found out that `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` has some relation to the issue.

Anyone know why this happens and what can be possible places to check in order to fix this?

Here is my test project setup to reproduce the problem:

```
minSdkVersion 16 and targetSdkVersion 23 using:

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NextActivity"/>
</application>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View iv = findViewById(R.id.iv_test);
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(iv, "test");

        findViewById(R.id.b_go).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                        android.support.v4.util.Pair.create(iv, "test")).toBundle();

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class), bundle);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NextActivity.java**

```
public class NextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);

        final View iv = findViewById(R.id.iv_test);
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(iv, "test");
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.scenetransitions.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="GO"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_next.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.scenetransitions.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_test"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is screenshot took in proper time during the transition:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>` you should **never ever** use `null` for window background. Replace it with `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`

When you set it to `null` Android doesn't know what to draw and it could draw any garbage from GPU. So you should explicitly specify transparent background.

Comment: Indeed that fixed the issue. Funny fact, I did try to change the windowBackground, but didn't remember that I have defined many styles so didn't remember the v21 version :D

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code, but i didn't get any drawing issues. I mean when the second page opens up, the image is a bit blurry(pixelated) that's cause of the small size of the actual image(if that's the case just use a bigger image in the second activity). May be its your device. I tested this in Moto E2. For me the transition is smooth, no drawing issues what so ever.

Comment: What is the platform version of your device?

Comment: Android 5.1 Lollipop

Comment: Tested it on Lenovo K3 note, Marshmallow 6.0 same output. No issues. Could you test it some other device and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: I found Samsung s7 with 6.0.1 to test with, the effect doesn't reproduce with that. Any idea if this might be Nexus 5x GPU issue?

Comment: I think so. Because i tested it on samsung tab(slowest thing i have) lollipop. It works fine. Let me ask you something, are you doing any memory heavy operations while the transition in your real application, you know like an internet connectivity, image grabbing from the phone storage, or something like that(I'm asssuming the code you have given here is from a dummy app)..?  If so then that could be the reason for the drawing issues.

Comment: The error produces with my real app and this dummy app, and the dummy app is practically no code at all.

Comment: Then it must be a GPU issue. Nothing to do about it.

Comment: Google play store scene transitions however work properly, so there must be a way but not sure what is needed.